# How can I merge table inside an other table base on the value of a field?

Tags: nushell

I have a table like this:

```
╭─────┬────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╮
│   0 │ ╭───┬────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╮ │
│     │ │ 0 │ 2023-09-22 17:49:03.301                                                                                                        │ │
│     │ │ 1 │ INFO:     10.0.0.30:49398 - "GET ..." 200 OK                                                                                   │ │
│     │ ╰───┴────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯ │
│   1 │ ╭───┬────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╮ │
│     │ │ 0 │ 2023-09-22 17:44:11.024                                                                                                        │ │
│     │ │ 1 │ INFO:     10.0.2.177:15974 - "GET ..." 404                                                                                     │ │
│     │ ╰───┴────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯ │
│   2 │ ╭───┬────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╮ │
│     │ │ 0 │ 2023-09-22 17:44:11.024                                                                                                        │ │
│     │ │ 1 │ INFO:     10.0.0.30:47184 - "GET ..." 500                                                                                      │ │
│     │ ╰───┴────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯ │
```

How can I merge line 1 for each cells if the date from line 0 is the same?
To add more context it's a display of AWS logs and I want to merge the lines that are from the same request (so with the same timestamp) to have a better view of the logs.

In the example above I would like to have a new table (or the previous one updated) to have something like this:

```
╭─────┬────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╮
│   0 │ ╭───┬────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╮ │
│     │ │ 0 │ 2023-09-22 17:49:03.301                                                                                                        │ │
│     │ │ 1 │ INFO:     10.0.0.30:49398 - "GET ..." 200 OK                                                                                   │ │
│     │ ╰───┴────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯ │
│   1 │ ╭───┬────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╮ │
│     │ │ 0 │ 2023-09-22 17:44:11.024                                                                                                        │ │
│     │ │ 1 │ INFO:     10.0.2.177:15974 - "GET ..." 404                                                                                     │ │
|     | |   | INFO:     10.0.0.30:47184 - "GET ..." 500                                                                                      │ │
│     │ ╰───┴────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯ │
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming, the underlying data structure is two nested arrays of strings like below:

```bash
[
  ['2023-09-22 17:49:03.301', 'INFO:     10.0.0.30:49398 - "GET ..." 200 OK'], 
  ['2023-09-22 17:44:11.024', 'INFO:     10.0.2.177:15974 - "GET ..." 404'], 
  ['2023-09-22 17:44:11.024', 'INFO:     10.0.0.30:47184 - "GET ..." 500']
]
```

Then, you can use [`group-by`](https://www.nushell.sh/commands/docs/group-by.html) to group the input array by their first items (the date lines) using column `0`, then iterate over the groups using [`items`](https://www.nushell.sh/commands/docs/items.html#frontmatter-title-for-filters) to capture both their grouping key (the date) and the array of input values grouped together. For [`each`](https://www.nushell.sh/commands/docs/each.html#frontmatter-title-for-filters), take the latter, skip over their first items (the common date lines) using [`skip`](https://www.nushell.sh/commands/docs/skip.html#frontmatter-title-for-filters) with amout `1`, and [`flatten`](https://www.nushell.sh/commands/docs/flatten.html) out their contents. Finally, [`prepend`](https://www.nushell.sh/commands/docs/prepend.html#frontmatter-title-for-filters) the captured dates to each group:

```bash
group-by 0 | items {|date, logs|
  $logs | each {skip 1} | flatten | prepend $date
}
```

```
╭───┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────╮
│ 0 │ ╭───┬──────────────────────────────────────────────╮ │
│   │ │ 0 │ 2023-09-22 17:49:03.301                      │ │
│   │ │ 1 │ INFO:     10.0.0.30:49398 - "GET ..." 200 OK │ │
│   │ ╰───┴──────────────────────────────────────────────╯ │
│ 1 │ ╭───┬────────────────────────────────────────────╮   │
│   │ │ 0 │ 2023-09-22 17:44:11.024                    │   │
│   │ │ 1 │ INFO:     10.0.2.177:15974 - "GET ..." 404 │   │
│   │ │ 2 │ INFO:     10.0.0.30:47184 - "GET ..." 500  │   │
│   │ ╰───┴────────────────────────────────────────────╯   │
╰───┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯
```